# is it possible to write a pytest friendly .py that runs as a standalone?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a script that can generate a bunch of pytest friendly tests (py script) based on a template defined by the user.

I'd like to embedded all tests and logic w/in this one generated script and have pytest run against it.  This includes receiving command line parameters and parse them appropriately.  In short, is it possible to do something like the following with pytest?

```
def test_1():
   # some tests

def test_2():
   # some more tests
```

etc...

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   # parse command line parameters and setup tests
   pytest.main()  # run pytest on this file
```

Comment: Can you be more specific in explaining what you want? `pytest.main([__file__])` will run the tests defined in the file where you call it.

Comment: under unittest, i can define all my tests in one file and in my "main", I can run unittest.main() and it will find all my "test_*" functions and execute them.  I'd like to do the same with pytest and not have to use conftest.py to define my command line arg parser or any other external file for that matter.  I just want a standalone py that my user can run 'python mytest.py' and have pytest execute all the tests inside it.

Comment: Define the tests in some file `mytest.py`, put `if __name__ == "__main__": import pytest; pytest.main([__file__])` and running `python mytest.py` will run all the tests in that file.

Comment: if I understand this correctly, this will launch a new instance of the test engine correct?  so if I were to parse sys.argv prior to running pytest.main() and store it in some global vars, it won't work.

Comment: You can add the arguments to the parameters of pytest.main. `pytest.main([some_arg, __file__])`

Comment: where can I parse the 'some_arg' args passed to the pytest.main()?  as I understand it, I need to define a pytest_addoption() method in conftest.py to define the options allowable in my test module.